# Using Selenium and Chromedriver in Google Colab

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using following code to extract the reviews from amazon product page. I am running it in Google colab. The code runs fine and does not show any error. But it does not open chrome and perform the function. Please check what's the error?

```
# install selenium
!pip install selenium

# install chromedriver
!apt-get update
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin

# set options to be headless, ..
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

# open it, go to a website, and get results
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)
driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/Under-Armour-Charged-Assert-Black/dp/B087TQBBXD/")

# wait for the page to load
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

# locate all elements with the specified xpath
elements = driver.find_elements(by='xpath', value="//span[@class='a-size-base review-text']")

# print the text of each element
for element in elements:
  print(element.text)

# close the driver
driver.quit()
```

Comment: `options.add_argument('--headless')` means that no browser window is opened

Comment: amazon has guessed that its a bot, and you are getting this message `Enter the characters you see below
Sorry, we just need to make sure you're not a robot. For best results, please make sure your browser is accepting cookies.
Type the characters you see in this image:
Try different image
Continue shopping
Conditions of Use Privacy Policy
© 1996-2014, Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates` , you can check this by `print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body").text)`